# ServerRoot must be a valid directory on Mac

Tags: apache

Just trying to install Apache on Mac (Catalina) following this [tutorial](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions). Once installed, I receive an error as ServerRoot directory is not correct when trying to run Apache.

Even changing this directory to the correct one, I continue having the same problem:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 31 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf:
>   ServerRoot must be a valid directory

Any advice?

Comment: Sounds like you have a Syntax error on line 31 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic on why this question is off topic on Stackoverflow.